# Wordpress can´t find file

Tags: php, wordpress

I hope my title isn´t too ´general´ but I hope someone here can help me.

Since this was my time working with WordPress i´ve stumbled upon a lot of issues but after looking at all the premade functions I was able to solve them eventually. However now I can´t seem to solve it.

I want to know if a file exists.

So basically I did this:

```
$filename = IMG_PATH.'exampleImage.png';

  if(file_exists($filename)){
      echo 'The file '. $filename .' exists';
  }else{
      echo 'The file '. $filename .' does not exist';
  }
```

when I run this it says `path/to/image/exampleImage.png` does not exist.

Alright maybe the path is wrong or something. So to test I added:

```
<?php echo '<img src="'.IMG_PATH.'exampleImage.png">'; ?>
```

beneath my if statement and ran the code. The image shows just fine in my browser.

This means that `IMG_PATH.'exampleImage.png'` exists however in my IF i can't seem the find it.

Am I being stupid right now and made a super stupid mistake or what happened? I hope a fresh pair of eyes can solve my problem. Thanks!

EDIT:

Alright since the path from IMG_PATH seems to be relative as people said. Let me add another example.

Why can't i include the javascript file in my header?

Right now i have the whole javascript placed in the header. But since this WordPress theme has it's own folder of javascript files I decided to place it in there. Let's say it's named `jsFile.js`.

It uses the `JS_PATH` to find it's path to the JS folder. Similar as `IMG_PATH`.

When I try to include it like:

```
<?php echo '<script src="'.JS_PATH.'jsFile.js"></script>'; ?>
```

It just doesn't work. But when I just do:

`<?php readfile(JS_PATH.'jsFile.js'); ?>`

it will show everything that's inside of the jsFile.js as plain text meaning the path is correct.

---

```
echoing IMG_PATH: http://[websitehere]/wp-content/themes/[themehere]/img/
```

Comment: Well URL path is different from the filesystem path. Your `IMG_PATH` is probably relative that's why you get a negative result.

Comment: wordpress path starts relative to the wp-content folder, whereas the file_exists functions starts from the root file system, so you have to add  {your wp folder/wp-content/IMG_PATH} - please also post the output of echoing IMG_PATH

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Alright that `file_exists` wasn't the problem I had. Since it's all about including a javascript file in my header. I hope this makes sense. (Ps i've added a new section in my question after the EDIT:)

Comment: @gantners If you look at my question now you can see i added a whole new section and the last line will show you what my echo img_path shows. hope this helps!

Comment: @Déjà vu So the echo brings up the http path. There you have it. to check for file_exists, you must specify the local file system path e.g. /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/some.img.
for wordpress there exist predefined vars like styleesheet directory. choose one of them to get your theme path and use that for checking if the file exists. See [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/665/how-do-i-get-the-theme-url-in-php)

Comment: @gantners I'm not good with wordPress but the `IMG_PATH` already uses the `template_directory`. This is what the IMG_PATH does: `DEFINE('IMG_PATH',get_template_directory_uri().'/img/');`. But as you can see after the EDIT. Maybe you can explain what happens with that javascript file. WHy i can read it out with read_file but can't include it in `<script>` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments above, an example for adding js files to a child theme, taken from [wordpress reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri)

[readfile](http://php.net/manual/de/function.readfile.php) reads the content of the file, that is what you do not want, instead the server wants to parse and interpret your js file in order to build up the html markup for your website.

Make your js files available to the theme using the enqueue function of wordpress:

```
<?php
    function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom_script',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jsFile.js',
        array('jquery')
    );
   }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

You can modify the js path as you wish.

Comment: I will accept your answer. It was not how I solved it but because of this answer i found out about the `wp_enqueue_script` and i noticed it was already an existing function for the other JS files. I just added one line and it works now. thanks!